# Will a Quartz CIFilter create a different output whether executed on GPU or CPU?

Tags: macos, image-processing, quartz-graphics

I'm stuck with a problem on CIFilters and applying them. Either the filter is only applied to 1/3 of an image (GPU) or the filter is only working only once (CPU). Redoing the same operation on CPU will cause the 1/3 image; redoing the operation on the same with CPU calculations, the CIFilter does not work/ is not applied.

I tried to add sample pictures, but I'm a starter here, so this is not allowed.Please have a look at my original post at Apple https://discussions.apple.com/message/16412850#16412850 . I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Questions:

- Why are is the CIFilter not working deterministic on CPU ?
- Why is the GPU renderer stopping exactly after one third of the image ?
- Is there a way to debug a CIFilter ? QuartzComposer only allows it given kernel code - but is there a debugger/logger ?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

PS.:
I've also tried by switching the graphics card, but that didn't help either.

Here is code, parts are derived from the ImageApp Example from Apple.

```
- (void)createCGImageAtPathNamed:(NSString*)destPath
{
    if (false == didInit)
        return ;

    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);


    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(leftCGImageRef);
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(leftCGImageRef);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0}, {width, height}};
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = rect.size.width*4;         //bytes per row - one byte each for argb
    bytesPerRow += (16 - bytesPerRow%16)%16;    

    CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, myColorspace, alphaInfo);

    NSDictionary *contextOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool: wantsSoftRenderer],kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer,nil];


    CIContext* cicontext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext: context options: contextOptions];
    CIImage *ciimgLeft = leftCIImage;
    CIImage *ciimgRight = rightCIImage;


    CIFilter *mFilter;

    [CIPlugIn loadAllPlugIns];
    mFilter = [[CIFilter filterWithName: @"CILightenBlendMode"] retain];
    [mFilter setValue: ciimgLeft forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [mFilter setValue: ciimgRight forKey: @"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage* resultingImage = [mFilter valueForKey: kCIOutputImageKey];

    CGRect extent = [ciimgLeft extent];

    [cicontext drawImage: resultingImage inRect:rect fromRect:extent];

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);

    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage: image];
    NSData *jpegData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];

    [jpegData writeToFile: destPath atomically: YES];
    [bitmapRep release];
    [mFilter release];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);
}
```